# How do I use single login for multiple web apps

Tags: c#, asp.net, membership, single-sign-on

I want to log in for 1 application and use the same login token to authenticate the second application. I have used the same application name so both applications use the same membership provider.....

I have 2 web applications, using asp.net 3.5, c#, hosted in IIS 7.0. I use the aspnet_membership provider for authentication/authorization

They are hosted side by side as 2 seperate applications . The question is can I log in for 1 application and be authenticated for the other by using the same log in....

Thanks in advance

Stuart

Comment: You might want to provide more details in your question. What technologies are you using to create your web applications, what authentication method and so on. Without details, you are not likely to get an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The technology behind Single Sign-On solutions cannot be explained in a few lines of code, it requires some reading/studying to look at the alternatives and how to implement them.

For instance you could take a look at [this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163520.aspx) about Single Sign-On using [Active Directory Federation Services](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc736690.aspx).

**UPDATE:** 
Here is a blogpost about [Single sign-on with Forms Authentication](http://weblogs.asp.net/hernandl/archive/2004/06/09/ssoformsauth.aspx).

Answer (score 3):

Its called Single Sign On - SSO and its fairly simple to do if your applications are hosted on the same domain (app1.domain.com and app2.domain.com - or - domain.com/app1 and domain.com/app2), its fairly straightforward to do so.

When you create a cookie using the Forms Authentication, set the domain as ".domain.com". 
Also, both the Applications would have to use the same Machine Key within web.config.

Check out http://www.codeproject.com/KB/web-security/aspnetsinglesignon.aspx and http://weblogs.asp.net/hernandl/archive/2004/06/09/ssoformsauth.aspx

Comment: thanks, seems like the sort of thing I want, I'll check it out